# Building a vanilla carousel - stuck on one peice of logic

Tags: javascript

Any mentorship or guidance would be most welcomed.

I am trying to make a vanilla JS carousel and I am so close to realising my objective to build one.

However; I cannot seem to get the prev or next buttons to move the carousel backwards or forwards. The buttons "work" they go up and down in value; they do not change the style. I can see that console logging the values.

- I've tried passing the function back onto itself - however, I cannot think of a way of initialising the start frame; if that is the best way.
- Adding the slideIndex value into the style rule doesn't work. What I get is if you keep on pressing "prev" for example; eventually, another frame randomly pops up below.

Any help would be very much welcomed.

On a side note - is there a better way to work with variable scoping; without everything requiring this?

```js
'use strict';
function carousel(n) {
  this.slideIndex = n;
  this.slides = document.querySelectorAll('.homepage_carousel_wrapper .homepage_carousel');
  [...this.slides].forEach(function(x) {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  });
  this.slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";  
  this.prev = function(n) {
    this.slideIndex += n;
    if (this.slideIndex < 1) {
      this.slideIndex = this.slides.length;
    }
    console.log(`${this.slideIndex}`);
    this.slides[this.slideIndex].style.display = "flex";  
  }
  this.next = function(n) {
    this.slideIndex += n;
    if (this.slideIndex > this.slides.length) {
      this.slideIndex = 1;
    }
    console.log(`${this.slideIndex}`);
    this.slides[this.slideIndex].style.display = "flex";  
    //carousel(this.slideIndex)
  }
};
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const hp_carousel = new carousel(3);
  let carouselPrev = document.getElementById('carousel_prev');
  carouselPrev.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    hp_carousel.prev(-1);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
  let carouselNext = document.getElementById('carousel_next');
  carouselNext.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    hp_carousel.next(1);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
});
```

```css
.homepage_carousel:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.homepage_carousel:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.homepage_carousel:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>carousel</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id='carousel_prev'>prev</a>
  <a id='carousel_next'>next</a>
  <div class='homepage_carousel_wrapper'>
    <div class='homepage_carousel'>
      <h1>Frame 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='homepage_carousel'>
      <h1>Frame 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='homepage_carousel'>
      <h1>Frame 3</h1>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modifications to the HTML and CSS, and have rewritten most of the JavaScript.

## Main Modifications

**HTML**

- Changed the controls from links to buttons.
- Moved the controls inside the carousel.

**CSS**

- Removed repeated CSS.

**JavaScript**

- ***Added spacing to make the code more readable.***
- ***Added a few comments to make the code easier to understand.***
- Modified the carousel constructor to allow multiple carousels to be made.
- Moved the control event listeners inside the carousel constructor.
- Replaced the `prev()` and `next()` functions with a `changeSlide()` function.

```js
'use strict';

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const hpCarousel = new carousel('homepage_carousel', 3);
});

function carousel(id, index) {
  // Set slide index and get slides
  this.slideIndex = index;
  const carousel = document.getElementById(id);
  this.slides = [...carousel.getElementsByClassName('slide')];

  // Get controls and add event listeners
  const prev = carousel.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0];
  const next = carousel.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];

  prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.changeSlide(-1);
  });

  next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.changeSlide(1);
  });

  // Functions for managing slides
  this.hideAll = function() {
    this.slides.forEach(function(slide) {
      slide.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }

  this.show = function() {
    this.hideAll();
    this.slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'flex';
  }

  this.changeSlide = function(amount) {
    this.slideIndex += amount;
    this.slideIndex = (this.slideIndex > this.slides.length) ? 1 :
      (this.slideIndex < 1) ? this.slides.length : this.slideIndex;

    this.show();
  }

  // Show the specified slide
  this.show();
}
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='homepage_carousel'>
  <button class='prev'>prev</button>
  <button class='next'>next</button>

  <div>
    <div class='slide'>
      <h1>Frame 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='slide'>
      <h1>Frame 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='slide'>
      <h1>Frame 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am speechless. Thank you for your assistance. I've learnt more from your post than, I've learnt in a month. Many thanks.